# How to add a primary literature bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biblatex-chicago

In Indological literature there's the convention of having two separate bibliographies: One for secondary literature, which can be handled more or less straightforward by existing types and fields already present in biblatex(-chicago), and a primary literature one, for which in a previous publication project I had to resort to ugly hacks like abusing the `title` field for the name of the work and, optionally, its author, then hardcoding all the actual bibliographical information into the `note` field. How ugly was that, as in the following, which is roughly how I used to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{pri.bib}

@misc{Kuṭṭanīmata,
title = {Kuṭṭanīmata \emph {of Dāmodaragupta}},
note = {\textit{Dāmodaraguptaviracitaṃ Kuṭṭanīmatam:  The Bawd’s Counsel, Being an Eighth-century Verse Novel in Sanskrit by Dāmodaragupta, Newly Edited and Translated into English}, edited and translated by Csaba Dezső and Dominic Goodall.  Groningen Oriental Studies 23.  Groningen: Egbert Forsten, 2012},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{sec.bib}

@book{DezsoGoodall2012,
title = {Dāmodaraguptaviracitaṃ Kuṭṭanīmatam},
subtitle = {The Bawd’s Counsel, Being an Eighth-century Verse Novel in Sanskrit by Dāmodaragupta, Newly Edited and Translated into English},
editor = {Csaba Dezső and Dominic Goodall},
translator = {Csaba Dezső and Dominic Goodall},
series =  {Groningen Oriental Studies},
number = {23},
location = {Groningen},
publisher = {Egbert Forsten},
year = {2012},
}

\end{filecontents*}


\begin{filecontents*}{biber.conf}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" bmap_overwrite="1">
      <map>
        <per_datasource>pri.bib</per_datasource>
        <map_step map_field_set="KEYWORDS" map_field_value="pri"/>
      </map>
      <map>
        <per_datasource>sec.bib</per_datasource>
        <map_step map_field_set="KEYWORDS" map_field_value="sec"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>

\end{filecontents*}


\addbibresource{pri.bib}
\addbibresource{sec.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[title=Primary Sources, keyword=pri,heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[title=Secondary Sources, keyword=sec,heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

For a new project I am now thinking to do it properly, but am not quite sure how to go about it. Maybe I could create new types, say `@pri-book`, for which I guess I'd have to copy the definition of `@book` from chicago-authordate.bbx, and extend it by two extra fields, e.g. `pri-title`, containing the Sanskrit title of the work, and the optional `pri-author`, which of course would also need to be defined, and change the order of fields for the year to be output at the end of the entry?

Comment: Could you say a bit more about what you mean by 'primary' and 'secondary' here? It is obviously not the sense I'm familiar with at all: here the primary and secondary literature apparently consists of exactly the same sources, differently formatted.

Comment: @cfr Yes, taking exactly the same book as example for both categories might have been a bit confusing. The idea is that if I talk about the Kuṭṭanīmata, quoting some of it, readers should understand what edition I am referring to, or sometimes it might even be manuscripts for unedited texts. Whereas I might deal with the same book as secondary literature when taking reference to something added by the editors, such as their introduction.

Comment: Then it is just different formats for perfectly standard `.bib` entries? I don't see why you'd need special types here at all. One entry for the item and it gets formatted different ways. After all, that's sort of the point of Biblatex/Biber/BibTeX, isn't it? You don't change the database because you want a different format - otherwise, you might as soon use `thebibliography`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Update

Here's a version that keeps the `author` and `title` separate. It copes with different languages OK. I've also kept your source map and used the source map to set the `sortkey` to `title` so that entries are sorted by title rather than author. The `relatedoptions={dataonly,useditor=false,usetranslator=false}` ensures that the related entry does not appear in the bibliography unless explicitly cited and the editor and translator appear after the title.

It's not super clever, but is a reasonably place to start.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,language=auto,autolang=other]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{pri.bib}
@misc{Kuṭṭanīmata,
  entrysubtype = {classical},
  author = {Dāmodaragupta},
  title = {Kuṭṭanīmata},
  related = {DezsoGoodall2012},
  relatedoptions = {dataonly,useeditor=false,usetranslator=false}
}
@misc{Title:fr,
  entrysubtype = {classical},
  author = {Author},
  title = {Title},
  langid = {french},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sec.bib}
@book{DezsoGoodall2012,
  title = {Dāmodaraguptaviracitaṃ Kuṭṭanīmatam},
  subtitle = {The Bawd’s Counsel, Being an Eighth-century Verse Novel in Sanskrit by Dāmodaragupta, Newly Edited and Translated into English},
  editor = {Csaba Dezső and Dominic Goodall},
  translator = {Csaba Dezső and Dominic Goodall},
  series =  {Groningen Oriental Studies},
  number = {23},
  location = {Groningen},
  publisher = {Egbert Forsten},
  year = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{pri.bib}
\addbibresource{sec.bib}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{pri.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=pri]
      \step[fieldsource=title, final]
      \step[fieldset=sortkey, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}
\newbibmacro*{pri:titleofauthor}{%
  \ifentrytype{misc}
    {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}
       {\ifbibliography
         {\printfield{title}%
          \ifnameundef{author}
            {}
            {\setunit*{\addspace}%
             \bibstring{of}%
             \setunit*{\addspace}%
             \printnames{author}%
             \clearname{author}}%
          \clearfield{title}}
         {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{title}}%
          \ifnameundef{labelname}
            {}
            {\setunit*{\addspace}%
             \bibstring{of}%
             \setunit*{\addspace}%
             \printnames{labelname}}%
          \clearfield{labeltitle}%
          \clearname{labelname}}}
       {}}
    {}}
\xpretobibmacro{cite}
  {\usebibmacro{pri:titleofauthor}}
  {}
  {}
\xpatchbibdriver{misc}
  {\usebibmacro{bibindex}}
  {\usebibmacro{bibindex}\usebibmacro{pri:titleofauthor}}
  {}
  {}
\begin{document}
Filler text \autocite{Kuṭṭanīmata}.

Filler text \autocite{Title:fr}.

Filler text \autocite{DezsoGoodall2012}.

\printbibliography[title=Primary Sources, keyword=pri,heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[title=Secondary Sources, notkeyword=pri,heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## Original answer

This looks like a good candidate for the `related` feature of `biblatex`. You can set the `entrysubtype` field to `classical` for your primary source to get the output you want without really doing anything clever.

Ideally you'd want to separate `author` and `title` of your Kuṭṭanīmata entry, but if you don't want to modify the drivers, you could leave everything in the `title` field as you have now.

How's this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Kuṭṭanīmata,
  entrysubtype = {classical},
  title = {\mkbibemph{Kuṭṭanīmata} of Dāmodaragupta},
  related = {DezsoGoodall2012},
  relatedoptions = {dataonly,useeditor=false,usetranslator=false},
  keywords = {pri}
}
@book{DezsoGoodall2012,
  title = {Dāmodaraguptaviracitaṃ Kuṭṭanīmatam},
  subtitle = {The Bawd’s Counsel, Being an Eighth-century Verse Novel in Sanskrit by Dāmodaragupta, Newly Edited and Translated into English},
  editor = {Csaba Dezső and Dominic Goodall},
  translator = {Csaba Dezső and Dominic Goodall},
  series =  {Groningen Oriental Studies},
  number = {23},
  location = {Groningen},
  publisher = {Egbert Forsten},
  year = {2012},
  keywords = {sec}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Filler text \autocite{Kuṭṭanīmata}.

Filler text \autocite{DezsoGoodall2012}.

\printbibliography[title=Primary Sources, keyword=pri,heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[title=Secondary Sources, keyword=sec,heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Quite an improvement! Was it necessary to join the two bib files for the `related` feature to work, or why did you do that? And I might indeed want to separate the title and author for the primary reference entries, particularly so as it will be used for the sorting. For that I'd have to copy the relevant definitions in chicago-dates-common.cbx, changing them to `\renewbibmacro`, and modify them?

Comment: Not necessary to combine the bib files. You can continue to use your current method for specifying which entries are primary and secondary and storing them in different bib files. I only did it the way I did to make the code a bit more minimal. I'll put an example together that produces the kind of output you want.

Comment: Actually, I'm not clear enough on exact behaviour you want to separate author and title. Can you explain how things should be sorted?

Comment: In many cases you won't have an author at all, so then of course only the title of the work should be displayed. If there's an author, one should first have the title of the work, and then "of" and the name of the author. The sorting should be by according to the title, and use the [Sanskrit alphabetical order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329677/59023), but that only for the primary references.

Comment: Thinking of it, I'm afraid there's going to be a further complication, namely that a few of the contributions in the next project are going to be in French, in which case one will need the corresponding strings in French, the multilingual setup probably going to be dealt with by polyglossia.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Assuming I want a book to appear only in the primary references, not in the secondary ones, how would I do that? The "related" seems to work similar to the `\cite` commands, making the entry appear in the (secondary) bibliography, but in most cases I wouldn't want that.

Comment: Hmmm I would have thought it shouldn't do that. I'll look into it. You could add `skipbib` to the `relatedoptions` field.

Comment: Ah. I remember. by default `relatedoptions` is set to `dataonly` on so it doesn't appear in bibliography. But when we set it to something else, the `dataonly` option is overwritten. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I would like to now use the `indexing=true`-option of biblatex-chicago, but suppress the titles of secondary literature items. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437287/59023) is the follow-up question.

Comment: Would there be a way to NOT use the author when using the `\cite` command in your text, but only display his name in the bibliography? So far, I achieved that by `useauthor=false` as an option automatically added to all primary sources, but would like to get rid of that.