# Position of addendum field with regard to the related field

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

The field `addendum` is supposed to be displayed at the very end of a bibliography entry. But in the case in which that item contains a `related` string, this is not true anymore. Is there any other field one could use instead of `addendum`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,indexing=true]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{RauSūSaṃ,
entrysubtype = {classical},
title = {Rauravasūtrasaṃgraha},
addendum = {Also consulted: Mysore ORI MS B~776.},
related = {Bhatt1961},
relatedoptions = {useeditor=false,usetranslator=false,skipbib=true},
}

@book{Bhatt1961,
editor = {N. R. Bhatt},
title = {Rauravāgama},
volume = {1},
series = {Publications de l'Institut Français d'Indologie},
number = {18.1},
publisher = {IFP},
location = {Pondicherry},
year = {1961},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: bibliography]

EDIT:

As as clarification: The relationship is one of primary and secondary bibliography, more or less as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415899/how-to-add-a-primary-literature-bibliography). Thus the two entries would normally be displayed in two separate bibliographies, which I left out from the example above, to keep it simple.

In theory, a beautiful solution might be to have the `addendum` be displayed after the `related` information only for `entrysubtype = {classical}`. Anyway, I can also work with the current behaviour, copying `Bhatt1961` to a new entry which gets only sourced by the respective primary bibliography entry, and adding the addendum field there. Not quite ideal, but as these cases are rare it wouldn't be too much of a problem.

EDIT:

I now realize that I do have quite a number of entries of this kind, pertaining to different papers in the same book, all of them having their own bibliographies, so a cleaner solution would be great. I've thought of using the `\fullcite` command in the note field for the main reference, and the addendum for "Also consulted.":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,indexing=true]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{RauSūSaṃ,
entrysubtype = {classical},
title = {Rauravasūtrasaṃgraha},
addendum = {Also consulted: Mysore ORI MS B~776.},
note = {\fullcite{Bhatt1961}},
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{RauSūSaṃ2,
entrysubtype = {classical},
title = {Rauravasūtrasaṃgraha},
addendum = {Also consulted: Mysore ORI MS B~776.},
related = {Bhatt1961}, 
relatedoptions = {useeditor=false,usetranslator=false,skipbib=true},
}

@book{Bhatt1961,
editor = {N. R. Bhatt},
title = {Rauravāgama},
volume = {1},
series = {Publications de l'Institut Français d'Indologie},
number = {18.1}, 
publisher = {IFP},
location = {Pondicherry},
year = {1961},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

which almost works, except for two points:

1. I would need another command instead of `\fullcite`, one which keeps the year at the end. Would it be possible to call whichever internal command takes care of the regular formatting of the entry, such as in the third entry, i.e. RauSūSaṃ2, with the year at the end instead of after the editor?
2. I would want to exclude Bhatt1961 from the bibliography. Unless it gets cited in the paper of course. If it was done via related entry that would have been done by `skipbib=true` as one of the `relatedoptions`. Here I would probably want to do something like in the third approach in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111375/59023). I would have to check it manually, but that's okay.

Alternatively, is there any field one could use as the very final field to be displayed, even after `related`? Or, how would I define such a field? Or, how would I change the order of display of `related` and `addendum`?

Comment: Yeah, usually `addendum` is the last regular field (or one of the last) in an entry, but `related` entries usually come after that. That's because `related` is a different entry, having the `addendum` of the original entry come after the `related` entry might cause confusion as to where it belongs. I'm not sure if `related` is the best way to model the relation between the two entries. Maybe `crossref` would be more appropriate? (I don't understand how the two sources go together, so this is just guessing.)

Comment: @moewe See my edit above for the relationship of the two entries.